# how to get rid of expired session errors?

Tags: php, session

i have a page that has session_start() and this happends locally not sure if it shows on the server but everytime the session expires and the user gets redirected to the login page. i keep seeing these session errors.

and what i did was go into those directorys and delete the sessions by one by one. and i still see them. how can i get rid of these? is it possible that i need to set the permission that is holding these sessions to full access? there pretty annoying. thanks

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/sess_e6e1923ad0afdd566ba14f0dcfb8d1c9, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /Volumes/www/iadprint/iadadmin/index.php on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /Volumes/www/iadprint/iadadmin/index.php:2) in /Volumes/www/iadprint/iadadmin/index.php on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Volumes/www/iadprint/iadadmin/index.php:2) in /Volumes/www/iadprint/iadadmin/index.php on line 2
```

Comment: i set the permission on the directory to read & write to all. and it worked. is this something secure or there is an alternative? thanks

Comment: theres no particular reason why you shouldnt do it but i also don't know what your environment looks like. you may want to htaccess and server config secure your foldres that don't need to be public. or best put a a document root for public access that is located within your application and has no protected child folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second two errors are the result of the first one being outputted to the page. So the only real issue is the first error.

1. First suggestion is to make sure nothing is being echoed or outputted to the page before `session_start()` is called. Also make sure there is no whitespace or line breaks before the first `<?php` call.
2. A possible solution (if that is no the issue) is (not confirmed or guaranteed) to call `session_id()` before `session_start()`.

Answer (score -1):

as long as the session is created by the same user that wants to access it afterwards, there shouldnt be a permission problem. however i don't know what operating system you are on or whatever settings you have active. it could for example be appguard.

you can try setting the permissions of the folder holding the sessions to public read+write or try to adjust tue umask of your webserver user.

the second two errors are probably caused by the output of the first one. so only the first is to worry about.

Comment: im on a mac snow leopard running mamp